# Internal forces in a truss and its geometry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, statics

I'm to work out the internal forces in a truss, but I can't get my head around the geometry of the truss itself. I'm starting to think there may have been information on the diagram which I missed. Could I get some directions on how to find x?

[image]

Comment: I suspect that you are meant to assume the truss is symmetric, and which point I think you have enough data.

Comment: Video that analyses precisely this structure from the Wikiengineering channel: - Working out the angles - From these, how to find lengths and distances - This part one of a 4 part series: this is not a one step, 5 min problem. <https://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=BE&v=DS0LCnSpkFc>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reconstruct the geometry with [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/). Look for equidistant triangles.

[image: Screenshot]